# When to call glDeleteBuffers()

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

Currently, I have a native function set up that I'm calling during onDestroy() on the Java side. I'm calling free() on any native side pointers I have memory allocated for. If I also call glDeleteBuffers() in this function, I get a an error in logcat stating

> call to OpenGL ES API with no current
>   context (logged once per thread)

I gather I could interrupt the Back Button Press and handle things more gracefully, but in the case the app is killed another way, what is the best way to make sure I've freed the gl resources in a timely manner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the context is destroyed it frees all it's resources (textures, buffers etc.) so it is not necessary to delete them manually.

Comment: Really? Well heck... that's great to know.